# CSS .navbar scrolling issue

Tags: css, navbar, padding

I have an issue with my .navbar. In the first image, I changed the paddings of text and logo and this is what I want.

first image

[image: first image]

While scrolling my hover effects changes my navbar's paddings.

And finally, the real problem, after scrolling down and up, the .navbar paddings remains different from first image

second image

[image: second image]

I have following css codes and I could not solve this problem myself. I hope you guys can give me some advice.

```css
.navbar-brand {
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin: 0!important;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
 margin-right: 10px!important;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    margin-left: 6px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: #999;
 display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
    padding: 28px 15px 15px 15px;
 overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a {
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a i {
 margin: 0 -2px 0 -5px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:after {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 content: '';
 left: 50%;
 display: block;
 height: 5px;
 width: 5px;
 opacity: 0;
 margin: 0 0 -3px -2px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 position: absolute;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.active:after {
 opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    width: 180px;
 background-color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.drop:hover .dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
}

.dropdown li, .sup-dropdown li {
 position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.dropdown li:first-child, .sup-dropdown li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}

.dropdown li a, .sup-dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 11px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


.dropdown > li:hover > a, .sup-dropdown li:hover > a {
 padding-left: 18px;
}

.dropdown li a i {
 margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .sup-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 180px;
 background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: margin-top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li.drop .dropdown li:hover .sup-dropdown {
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post html as well. It will be way more helpful.